# Lubuntu & GT730 - no output on DVI

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, dvi

I'm trying to setup an extended desktop layout: primary output on VGA, extended desktop on HDMI and a mirror of the extended desktop on DVI.

I'm running an 'out of the box' Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, the graphics card is an Nvidia GT730 DDR3 (64-bit) which supports three monitors. However I'm getting no joy on the DVI output. I've tested the DVI cable on another machine and there is no issue there.

Short of the DVI port itself being faulty (I need to wait a couple of days for a spare cable to try) what else can I test for?